# Access protected variable

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

Given the following code, why is it that I'm able to access a protected variable in a class that is neither in the same package nor extends the class that declared the variable?

```
public class B{
     protected String s = "B1";
     public B() {};

}

public class P{
     public void out(Object o){
         System.out.println(o);}
}

public class M{
    B b = new B();
    P.out(b.s);}
```

Why can the out method access b.s?

Comment: It's not the `P#out` method which "accesses" the variable, but the class `M`.

Comment: its strange that the P.out can be done without P.out being static :D.

Comment: Since your code is not complete, I can't be certain, but B and M are probably in the same package.

Comment: Yeah and no constructor/method either, this is just a hastily thrown together example that does not realistically represent the code that this is being asked about. Post the -actual- code, with package statements.

Comment: Add the package statements, otherwise, this question will be closed, as not to have enough information.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I assumed that since I did not explicitly create a package, the classes weren't in the same package. I did not know that all classes are automatically put into a default package. Sorry once again, I'm still new to Java.

Answer (score 0):

S is accessable because it is protected not private. You can call it through B.

Comment: that depends all of in what package the class M and B are, without package declaration and real compiling code(this code won't compile!) you can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you are getting package level access.  Look here for more information:
[In Java, difference between default, public, protected, and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/in-java-whats-the-difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private)